# Chinese/Bopomofo not triggering PropertyChanged on bound Text property in wpf

Tags: wpf, binding, localization

When the user has set their Keyboard layout to: *Chinese(Traditional,Taiwan) Bopomofo* as their input language no binding happens as the user inserts text into the TextBox.
The binding only happens after the user loses focus on the textbox.

**EDIT:** The binding also triggers,once, when all text is deleted from the textbox, binding a empty string to the property.

In the view

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ChineseText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I tried to set xml:lang="zh-Hant" like so, which made no difference:

```
<TextBox xml:lang="zh-Hant" Text="{Binding ChineseText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Note: using *English(US) keyboard* layout, when the user inputs any az-AZ character the bound property gets updated as expected

**EDIT:** A regular TextChanged event handler fires whenever i input any character, but still nothing is bound to the property.